# Cant get button value when clicked the icon inside button in react js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So Im trying to get the value from a button. This my button:

```
<button
  className="toggle__btn"
  value={el._id}
  onClick={toggle}
>
     <i className="fa-solid fa-circle-info fs-4"></i>
</button>
```

This my function:

```
const toggle = (event) => {
    const id = event.target.value;
    console.log(id);
  };
```

The problem is I can't get the value if I click the icon, but I can when I click outside the icon but still inside the button(there is blank space outside the icon). I want it to return the id even when the icon is clicked. How to do so? Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Unlike `target`, [`currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) remains the same throughout the event propagation, even if the event bubbles up to a parent element. It always refers to the element that the event listener was attached to.

You can try using [`currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) to refer the element that attached the event. This will retrieve the `id` from the button element, whether you click on the icon or the blank space inside the button.

```
const toggle = (event) => {
  const id = event.currentTarget.value;
  console.log(id);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
const toggle = (event) => {
    const id = event.currentTarget.value;
    console.log(id);
};
```

> event.currentTarget tells us on which element the event was attached or the element whose eventListener triggered the event.

> event.target tells where the event started.

See https://medium.com/@etherealm/currenttarget-vs-target-in-js-2f3fd3a543e5

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling pointer events on the child:

```html
<button ...>
  <span className="icon">
     <i className="..."></i>
  </span>
</button>
```

in the css file:

```css
.icon {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Tried this and it works. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please use `currentTarget`

```js
const App = () => {    
    const toggle = (event) => {
        const id = event.currentTarget.value;
        console.log(id);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <button value="test val" onClick={toggle}>TEST</button>
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```